# Selenium testing - events seem not to be fired

Tags: javascript, events, selenium, glassfish, selenium-rc

I'm using embedded glassfish to deploy my web application and test it with arquillian remote control. While everything's been going nice so far, we found a problem when trying to deal with a suggestions feature in the application. It basically consists of a text box which offers a list of possibly matching items once 3 or more characters have been typed.

```
    <div class="uiModuleSelectingConcepts suggestion_${cc.id}">
    <div class="searchBox">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" 
                   class="sample" 
                   value="${cc.attrs.input_label}"
                   placeholder="${cc.attrs.input_label}"/>
                   <i></i>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <a4j:outputPanel id="suggestion_component_container"
                     styleClass="suggestionsWrapper" 
                     layout="block">
        <div class="suggestionsList_${cc.id}">
        </div>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</div>
```

Some events are added so these suggestions are properly displayed, as follows (in the following code, the parameter inputNode) is the textbox itself where the user types...there is where we add the events):

```
           this.addEventHandlers = function (inputNode, suggestionCallback, params) {
           var parent = this;
           inputNode
           /*
            * keypress event.
            */
           .keypress(function(event) {
               if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                   event.preventDefault();
               }
           })
           /*
            * keyup event. 
            */
           .keyup(function(event) {
                       switch (event.keyCode) {
                       /**
                        * Up arrow.
                        */
                       case 38: 
                           event.stopPropagation();
                           event.preventDefault();
                           var suggestionsWrapper = parent._params.list;
                           var currentSelectedValue = null;
                           if (suggestionsWrapper.find(".suggestionItem").length) {
                               if (suggestionsWrapper.find(".suggestionItem:first").hasClass("focused")) {
                                   suggestionsWrapper.find(".focused").removeClass("focused");
                                   suggestionsWrapper.find(".suggestionItem:last").addClass("focused");
                                   //currentSelectedValue =  suggestionsWrapper.find(".suggestionItem:last").val();
                               } else {
                                   suggestionsWrapper.find(".focused").removeClass("focused").prev().addClass("focused");
                               };
                               //set the selected value to input.
                               //console.debug("Current Valiue", suggestionsWrapper.find(".focused"));
                               var e = suggestionsWrapper.find(".focused");
                               if (e.length > 0) {
                                   //console.debug("Current e", e);
                                   currentSelectedValue =  typeof e  === 'undefined' ? null : e.attr('data-suggest');
                                   //console.debug("Current Valiue", currentSelectedValue);
                                   if (currentSelectedValue != null) {
                                       jQuery(this).val(Encoder.htmlDecode(currentSelectedValue));
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                           parent._blur = false;
                           break;
                       /**
                        * Down arrow.
                        */    
                       case 40: 
                           var suggestionsWrapper = parent._params.list;
                           var currentSelectedValue = null;
                           if (suggestionsWrapper.find(".suggestionItem").length) {
                               if (suggestionsWrapper.find(
                                       ".suggestionItem:last").hasClass("focused")) {
                                   suggestionsWrapper.find(".focused").removeClass("focused");
                                   suggestionsWrapper.find(".suggestionItem:first").addClass("focused");
                               } else {
                                   suggestionsWrapper.find(".focused").removeClass("focused").next().addClass("focused");
                               };
                               //console.debug("Current Valiue", suggestionsWrapper.find(".focused"));
                               var e = suggestionsWrapper.find(".focused");
                               //console.debug("Current e", e);
                               if (e.length > 0) {
                                   currentSelectedValue =  typeof e  === 'undefined' ? null : e.attr('data-suggest');
                                   //console.debug("Current Valiue", currentSelectedValue);
                                   if (currentSelectedValue != null) {
                                       jQuery(this).val(Encoder.htmlDecode(currentSelectedValue));
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                           parent._blur = false;
                           break;
                       /**
                        * ENTER key
                        */
                       case 13: 
                           event.stopPropagation();
                           event.preventDefault();
                           var suggestionsWrapper = parent._params.list;
                           var oConcept = suggestionsWrapper.find(".focused");
                           if (typeof oConcept !== "undefined") {
                               oConcept.trigger("click");
                           }
                           parent._blur = true;                            
                           parent._cleanSuggestions();
                           jQuery(this).blur();
                           break;
                       /**
                        * ESC key event.
                        */    
                       case 27: 
                           event.stopPropagation();
                           event.preventDefault();
                           var sValue = jQuery(this).attr("data-default");
                           sValue = jQuery.trim(sValue);
                           if (sValue === jQuery(this).attr("data-default")) {
                               jQuery(this).addClass("sample").blur();
                           }
                           parent._blur = true;
                           parent._cleanSuggestions();
                           jQuery(this).val("");
                           jQuery(this).blur();
                           break;
                       default:
                           var suggestionsWrapper = parent._params.list;
                           //var typeRight = jQuery(this).parents(".tabContent").attr("id");
                           var sValue = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val());
                           //var oThisInput = jQuery(this);
                           if (sValue.length > MEDIA.configuration.SUGGESTION_LIMIT) {
                               suggestionsWrapper.find(".suggestionItem").remove();
                               global.uiDelay( function() {      
                                   parent.displayLoading();
                                   suggestionCallback(sValue, MEDIA.util.getTrueFalseValue(parent._params.retrieveOnlyClasses) ? suggestOnlyConcepts : "");
                               }, 1000);
                           } else {
                               parent.writeMore();
                           }
                           parent._blur = true;
                           break;
                       };
                   }).keydown(function(event) {
                   switch (event.keyCode) {
                       case 38: // up
                           event.stopPropagation();
                           event.preventDefault();
                           break;
                       case 40: // down
                           event.stopPropagation();
                           event.preventDefault();
                           break;
                       default:
                       break;
                   };
           }).focus(function() {
               jQuery(this).val("");
               parent._blur = true;
              // when suggestions lose focus
           }).blur(function() {
               if (parent._blur) {
                   jQuery(this).val("");
                   parent._cleanSuggestions();
               }
           });
       };
```

When the application is deployed normally (for no testing purposes, without selenium) it works as expected and when typing something the suggestions are displayed. However, when using Selenium no matter what is typed in the box nothing happens. We've tried many possibilities and combinations with .keyDown(), .keyPress(), .keyUp() with their char, keyCode and native variants. Also, .type(), .typeKeys()....all of them to no avail. It would seem as though for some reasons the events are ignored (the funny thing is, if we hand-type some text in the browser selenium opens for testing the application, the suggestions -do- display. They only don't when it's selenium doing the typing).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Not sure if I made complete sense, we'd be happy to clarify.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I used this simple testpage and jQuery 1.7.2 (the input to the first field should get copied into the another):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" />
        <input type="text" id="yourInput" />
        <script>
            $("#myInput").keyup(function(event) {
                $("#yourInput").val(this.value);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Let me state the annoying truth right in the beginning: *With WebDriver, everything works well and smoothly.*

```java
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("the path to the file");
driver.findElement(By.id("myInput")).sendKeys("Hello.");
driver.quit();
```

---

Anyway, what I was able to make it work in Selenium RC, too:

```java
sele.focus("id=myInput");
sele.keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_H));
sele.keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_E));
sele.keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_L));
sele.keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_L));
sele.keyPressNative(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.VK_O));
```

It kind of sucks, but it's the best I came up with where the event works.